# separate select clause and insert clause from sql string

Tags: java, regex, scala

I am trying to solve spark sql small files problem using the above approach , in my organization users pass in sql statements for example.

```
insert overwrite table x partition (column1) select * from y;
```

I can run the above sql in spark sql problem is it creates small files when compared with hive which has (merge small files= true) option etc ... which doesn't work in spark sql.

I came up with a work around like taking users sql statement and split into two parts select clause and insert clause , from the select clause create Dataframe first and get estimate size and calculate output files and insert into target table below is the example.

```
val df=sqlContext.sql(select * from y)
val size=SizeEstimator.estimate(df)
val outputFiles=size/256000
df.coleasce(outputFiles).wirte.mode.Append("x partition (column1)")
```

Is there a regex function or a library  in Java/Scala which can separate select clause and insert clause from a sql string ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following regular expression:

```
(.+?) (?=select)(.+)
```

The first capture group will contain the `INSERT` statement and the second one will contain the `SELECT` statement. Of course, a case-insensitive approach is recommended. You can see a working demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/FnSqX5/3).